# UICollectionView RTL direction

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview

The UIViewCollection in xcode have two direction states:
1. Horizontal
2. Vertical

I'm trying to use the Vertical state but make it so that the cell would show up from Right to Left. The default of course is Left to Right.

If i'm not clear i'll use an example:
Say i have a Vertical collectionView with 3 cells in a row and currently it shows only one row. When i add another cell (the 4th cell) i'd like it to appear on the bottom right corner of the collectionView. Currently it appears on the bottom left corner.

Any help would be great,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

I mirrored the collection view on its x pivot, but then i needed to mirror the cells as well. This was a bit of a pickle since UICollectionView has no "willDisplayCell" or anything similar.

This is how I did it:

Step one - in the viewDidLoad

```
self.collectionView.layer.transform = CATransform3DConcat(self.collectionView.layer.transform, CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI,0.0,1.0,0.0));
```

Step two - in the cellForItemAtIndexPath function

```
[self performSelector:@selector(flipCell:) withObject:cell afterDelay:0.0];
```

Step three - create new method

```
-(void)flipCell:(YESMyZoneCollectionViewCell *)cell{
    cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DConcat(cell.layer.transform, CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI,0.0,1.0,0.0));
}
```

Good luck...

---BIG EDIT---

The solution I gave above wasn't as good as I thought as the loading time on scrolling was huge.

So I did something similar without the "perform on delay" part.

I used this:

```
  -(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
      NSMutableArray *visibleCells = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.collectionView visibleCells]];

      for (int i = 0; i < [visibleCells count]; i++) {
          customCellObject *cell = [visibleCells objectAtIndex:i];
          if (cell.isFlipped == NO) {
              [self flipCell:cell];
          }
      }

  }
```

also I had to make the isFlipped property NO in the cellForItemAtIndexPath cause they come out non flipped when reused...